# Is it possible to add an Image to a CGFloat

Tags: uiimage, layer, cashapelayer

I am trying to create a progress bar that goes from 0%-100%. When the progress reaches 100%, I would like it to fade from the percentage to an image such as a check mark. I am setting this progress bar up as a CAShapeLayer and inside of it, I would like the the image to appear after it reaches 100. I see this animation done throughout various apps and I'm wondering if it is possible to do in Xcode. I have tried to do this by converting an image to a CAShapeLayer but it fails with a compiler error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type 'String'

I have used the code below, but it only shows the percentage of loading.
is it possible to be done?

```
  private func beginDownloadingFile() {
    print("Attempting to download file")

    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
    let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: operationQueue)

    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    let downloadTask = urlSession.downloadTask(with: url)
    downloadTask.resume()
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    let percentage = CGFloat(totalBytesWritten) / CGFloat(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.percentageLabel.text = "\(Int(percentage * 100))%"
        self.shapeLayer.strokeEnd = percentage
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
    }

    print(percentage)
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    print("Finished downloading file")
}
```

[image: percentage label that I want to change when reached 100%]

Thank you for explaining whether or not this can be accomplished in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, the reason for getting the error message `Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type 'String'`:

This is because in the last line (`UIImage(named: tick)`) in your snippet you try to initialize an UIImage with the UIImage constant *tick* you initialized two lines earlier.

---

What you try to accomplish is possible, but the way you try it will not work.
To help you with that, you should show how your UI is set up.

A possible solution:
Embed your percentageLabel in a UIStackView. Add a UIImageView to the stackview too. Set this ImageView to show the desired image and set the `isHidden` property of the imageView to `true`. 
When your progress reaches 100%, do the following:

```
percentageLabel.isHidden = true
imageView.isHidden = false
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I removed the tick image because It wasn't working how I wanted it to. I have updated my code above and added a picture to show more of what I mean. I would really appreciate it if you could help me with this!